# Failed: this.runnable is not a function

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor, runnable

When I try to run my protractor tests, the browser window launches and after a couple of seconds it closes without any activity on it. The console shows an error

```
1) Mail suite Send email
  - Failed: this.runnable is not a function
  - Failed: this.runnable is not a function

Executed 1 of 1 spec (1 FAILED) in 0.074 sec.
[08:01:26] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[08:01:26] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[08:01:26] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[08:01:26] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! protractor-example@1.0.0 e2e: `protractor protractor.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the protractor-example@1.0.0 e2e script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.
```

Here is my "spec.ts"

```
import {LoginPage} from '../page-objects/pages/login/login.po';
import {LoginPageHelper} from '../page-objects/pages/login/login-page.helper';
import {browser, By, element, ExpectedConditions} from 'protractor';
import {beforeEach, describe, it} from 'selenium-webdriver/testing';

describe('Mail suite', () => {
let loginPageHelper: LoginPageHelper;

beforeEach(() => {
    loginPageHelper = new LoginPageHelper();
});

it('Send email', async () => {
    const user1 = browser.params.user1;
    await loginPageHelper.goToPage();
    await LoginPage.username.sendKeys(user1.username);
    await element(By.id('identifierNext')).click();
    await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(LoginPage.password));
    await LoginPage.password.sendKeys(user1.password);
});
});
```

Please help me debug this error. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aah, I figured it out finally.
It is this line in my "spec.js" causing the above error

```
import {beforeEach, describe, it} from 'selenium-webdriver/testing';
```

As soon as I used beforeEach, webstorm gave a warning. When I tried to use the auto suggestion of webstorm, it asked to do "Alt+Enter". And it imported this line automatically.

Removing this Line has solved the problem.

Comment: Same happened to me writing unit tests in Angular CLI app - WebStorm for some reason doesn't recognize that the types are imported in tsconfig.spec.json, and still offers import help. One should not accept any import offered by WS for before*, after*, it, describe...

Comment: Completely agree with you. Additionally we should be careful enough while choosing the import offered by WS.

Answer (score 0):

something defined in

```
protractor.conf.js
```

function this.runnable? 
Maybe you want to define it

```
var runnable
```

instead of

```
this.runnable
```

Comment: Haven't used any such function in my protractor.conf.js

Comment: I figured out the problem, posted the answer.
Thank you for your help Sanja :-)